# IBM MobileFirst Platform Installation in Windows 8.1 64Bit

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I am using my office laptop (Lenovo vV310 - 8GB RAM - 64 Bit OS - Windows 8.1). I have been trying to fix an installation issue with IBM Mobile First Platform for the past few days. I downloaded the IBM Mobile First Developer Kit from  link http://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/products/en/MobileFirstPlatform/mobilefirst-deved-devkit-windows-8.0.0.0.exe

The problem is the installation software **InstallAnywhere** is not installing and gives the below warning.

**Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM**

[image]

I have JDK 1.8 installed in my notebook and I couldn't fix the issue. I have the java JDK and JRE bin paths set in the environment variables.

If any of you have fixed the issue, please share the solution.

Comment: 1.  check that the path is having IBM java. 2.  look at the logs and give us  more details on the error. Most likely the Java is not in path / not with executable privilleges.

Answer (score 2):

Open command line as Administrator and type following command.

```
[path of mobilefirst-devkit.exe] LAX_VM ["path of java.exe"]
```

> Usage

```
C:\Users\gaurab\Downloads\mobilefirst-deved-devkit-windows-8.0.0.0.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe"
```