# IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Devkit and 7.1/7.0 CLI installers fail to launch with "Windows error 2 occured while loading the Java VM" message

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-cli, installanywhere

After updating Oracle Java 8.0 to update 60 and above, IBM MobileFirst 7.0 / 7.1 CLI installers and IBM MobileFirst 8.0 Devkit installers fail to launch on Windows machines with the following error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Changes introduced by Oracle in Java 8 update 60 cause installers built using InstallAnywhere to fail with this error. This happens because with Oracle Java 8u60 and above, InstallAnywhere is unable to automatically locate where the latest supported JVM is on the Windows machine.

To learn more about the issue, see the [link](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/ISSUE/The-Without-VM-Installer-Fails-To-Launch-Using-Java-8-Update-60-On-Windows).

#### Resolution

One of the following approaches can resolve the issue:

*1. User Older version of the Java update*

The issue is not seen with updates earlier than Java 8u60. Alternatively, use Java 7.

*2. Tell InstallAnywhere which JVM you want to launch with*

As mentioned in the [link](https://flexeracommunity.force.com/customer/articles/ISSUE/The-Without-VM-Installer-Fails-To-Launch-Using-Java-8-Update-60-On-Windows) to workaround this issue, launch the installer via command line and tell InstallAnywhere which JVM you want to launch with using the `LAX_VM` parameter:

[image: Install MFP CLI with workaround]

[image: Install MFP 8 Devkit with workaround]

Answer (score 0):

Open command line as Administrator and type following command.

```
[path of mobilefirst-devkit.exe] LAX_VM ["path of java.exe"]
```

> Usage

```
C:\Users\gaurab\Downloads\mobilefirst-deved-devkit-windows-8.0.0.0.exe LAX_VM "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_112\bin\java.exe"
```

Duplicate of [IBM MobileFirst Platform Installation in Windows 8.1 64Bit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44482679/ibm-mobilefirst-platform-installation-in-windows-8-1-64bit)